# How do I connect a pre-made IBAction to my storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to implement a [dropdown menu](https://github.com/nmattisson/DropdownMenu/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aclosed) I found on github, it has pre-defined `IBAction`s and `IBOutlet`s. How do I connect theses outlets to the storyboard? Ctrl-drag is not working.

[image]

I believe my issue is that the file `DropdownMenuController` will not show up in the automatic section of files in the assistant editor. How would I add files?

[image]

### Update:

The `IBAction`s just aren't showing up anywhere. Here is an example:

All the outlets and actions that Xcode thinks exist

[image: IBActions and IBOutlets in Xcode]

But here in the Objective-C files are `IBAction`s that don't show up

[image: IBActions in Objective-C file]

Comment: Do the opposite, create a button in IB and ctrl drag it to the IBAction function

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to set the right View Controller Sub class to the view controller in the interface builder. check the following setting

[image]

Now you open the Utilities panels and go to the connections inspectors, not the source files.

[image]

Comment: The actions are not showing up in the utilities panel, see my update.

Answer (score 1):

Select viewController in storyboard, open utility bar and in connection inspector you will find methods which are mark with IBActions
[image]

After drag and drop you will prompt like this

[image]

select vc first in storyboard like this

[image]

Comment: The actions are not showing up in the utilities panel, see my update.

Comment: added another image see that, make sure you are selecting vc first